# Boxcarring (Multiple apex calls in single XHR) is not applicable for LWC?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I found a priority queue where it tries to make 2 low prioity apex calls in a single queue execution, However, when I refreshed the page in the network tab I see them as 2 seperate XHR requests instead of one boxcarred request, What is wrong?

Priority Queue Question : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/263382/how-to-turn-boxcarring-off-for-lwc-imperative-apex-method-calls

Comment: They're tweaking the performance every release and not really exposing any definitive "this is how it works". You seen https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/293025/799 related to your question?